# Do I really need the Hook useEffect() here?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

As a React Native newbie, I am working on an application for android. Basically, the app enables the user to filter a database according to specific search parameters.

Now I tried to convert a Class Component into a Functional component. The component just loads a prepopulated (Realm-) database, displays a search bar waiting for user input, performs a database query according to the user's input and shows the result.

In the "old" version, database setup was done during `componentDidMount()`, now I thought using the `useEffect()` Hook will do the job, since it works as a replacement for `componentDidMount()`. But I found that doing all the logic (which I actually wanted to put into the Hook) "naked" without any Hook works just fine.

I am so confused because of this behavior since I didn't expect that it would work this way. Surely I missed something. Googling unfortunately didn't give answers. Can you help me? Below is the code of the component I am talking of, `SearchBar.js`Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Header, Icon, Item, Input} from 'native-base';
import Realm from 'realm';
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {setInputValueSearchBar} from '../../../actions';

const SearchBar = props => {
  let [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(null);

  const sendInputValueToReduxStore = text => {
    setInputValue(text);
    props.setInputValueSearchBar(text);
  };

  // from here on, I wanted to use useEffect() ...
  const dogsSchema = {
    name: 'realm',
    properties: {
      name: 'string?',
      color: 'string?',
    },
  };

  let realm = new Realm({
    path: fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/default.realm',
    schema: [dogsSchema],
    readOnly: true,
  });

  const dogs = realm.objects('realm');
  let resultArray = [];

  const databaseRequest = () => {
    const query = inputValue;
    const result = inputValue
      ? dogs.filtered("name == '" + query + "'")
      : 'default';
    resultArray = Array.from(result);
    return resultArray.map(dog => (
      <Text className="dog" key={dog.name}>
        {dog.name}
      </Text>
    ));
  };

  //... until here

  const isText = props.text;

  return (
    <View>
      <Header searchBar rounded>
        <Item>
          <Icon name="ios-search" />
          <Input
            placeholder="Search"
            onChangeText={text => sendInputValueToReduxStore(text)}
            value={inputValue}
          />
        </Item>
      </Header>
      <View>{databaseRequest()}</View>
    </View>
  );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    inputValue: state.inputValue,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setInputValueSearchBar,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

This is the same component as Class Component before refactoring:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Header, Icon, Item, Input} from 'native-base';
import Realm from 'realm';
import fs from 'react-native-fs';
import {setInputValueSearchBar} from '../../../actions';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    inputValue: null,
  };

  sendInputValueToReduxStore(text) {
    this.setState({inputValue: text});
    this.props.setInputValueSearchBar(text);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const dogsSchema = {
      name: 'realm',
      properties: {
        name: 'string?',
        color: 'string?',
      },
    };

    let realm = new Realm({
      path: fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/default.realm',
      schema: [dogsSchema],
      readOnly: true,
    });

    const dogs = realm.objects('realm');
    let resultArray = [];

    this.databaseRequest = () => {
      const query = this.state.inputValue;
      const result = this.state.inputValue
        ? dogs.filtered("name == '" + query + "'")
        : 'default';
      resultArray = Array.from(result);
      return resultArray.map(dog => (
        <Text className="dog" key={dog.name}>
          {dog.name}
        </Text>
      ));
    };
  }

  render() {
    const isText = this.props.text;
    return (
      <View>
        <Header searchBar rounded>
          <Item>
            <Icon name="ios-search" />
            <Input
              placeholder="Search"
              onChangeText={text => this.sendInputValueToReduxStore(text)}
              value={this.state.inputValue}
            />
          </Item>
        </Header>
        {isText && (
          <View>
            <Text>{this.props.text}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
        <View>{this.databaseRequest()}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    inputValue: state.inputValue,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  setInputValueSearchBar,
};

export default withNavigation(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar),
);
```

Comment: Having code directly in the component function body means it will get executed on every component re-render, keep that in mind

Comment: @David, but is useEffect() Hook not also performed on every render?

Comment: @RuntimeError: The call to `useEffect` itself will, but `useEffect` will only invoke the function you pass it if the dependency array you pass it has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it'll work without `useEffect`.  But it'll also happen *every* time the component is re-rendered.  This might not be a problem in your application, for a couple of reasons:

- Maybe your component doesn't re-render often, depending on what state you're managing/updating and where
- Maybe the logic is a trivial resource drain and it doesn't matter if it's performed often

But if these things aren't the case, you'll likely want to measure and confirm what's happening.  Add some logging output to your setup logic here and observe in the log how often it's being invoked.

If it's not being re-invoked constantly (or at least not unreasonably often) then you can certainly keep it like this.  Just be aware that it could start being re-invoked constantly based on factors outside of this component, anything that would cause this component to be re-rendered.

If it *is* being re-invoked constantly, then that's what `useEffect` is for.  You can perform this logic only the first time the component is loaded by having no dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your logic
}, []);
```

Or you can add dependencies to trigger performing this logic any time those dependencies change.  For example, maybe re-invoke it any time your `inputValue` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your logic
}, [inputValue]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice explanation! Now I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, this is not a good approach.

The code is executed on each render, so each time a prop or state value changes, even if it's not related to that piece of code.

The `useEffect` hook also executes each render, BUT allows you to pass a dependency list (or an empty list if it has no dependencies, then it will execute once). Then the code will only execute when one of the dependencies changes.